# extracting motion-compensated frames during HEVC encoding

Tags: hevc, h.265

I am trying to analyze H.265 coding performance. Is there a way to export the predicted frames for H.265/HEVC encoding? Specifically, how should I obtain reconstructed frames after compensating with the motion vectors, but before applying the residual? Is there a way to do this with ffmpeg, or any other codec analysis tool?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with HM decoder. 
What you need to do is to find the exact line of the code in the `TDecCu.cpp` file, where two pointers `piResi` and `piPred` are accessed to be added and reconstruct the block. There, you may print `piPred` alone.

Comment: I am facing problems trying to reconstruct the full predicted image based on this approach because the dumped predicted values are written Prediction Unit-wise. As different PU sizes can be used by HEVC during encoding. How/where in the code would be possible to dump the "final" predicted image?

Comment: That's why this approach should be applied at the decoder side, and not encoder. At decoder, only one PU size is reconstructed for each pixel position. Which means that you can get the signal for whole frame simply by concatenating PU-wise signals.

Comment: Concatenation-only at decoder side seems insufficient because the reconstruction of the predicted image must be aware of the depth and partitioning decisions made at encoding-time. I was able to solve this by change the decoder source code, namely accessing the Top Left corner of each CU and getting the top left corner of each PU (represented as a TRect). In this way the absolute coordinate can be computed and used to populate an initialized image buffer